# Replace every \n after digit in ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

help me please with regular expression in ruby.

I have a text like

*1. Hello, World\n
2.**\n**
Good Morning\n*

I expect a two strings, but in original it has a three strings with bad 'new line - \n' character

Question how to replace 'bad' \n after '2.' and before 'Good Morning\n'
I have a trouble with thousands mistakes like this

Comment: use `gsub` method in ruby. See the ruby 1.9.3 documentation on [strings](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could remove the 'bad' newline character like this

```
string = "1. Hello, World\n 2.\n Good Morning\n"
new_string = string.gsub(/(\d+\.)\n/, '\1') #=> "1. Hello, World\n 2. Good Morning\n"
```

This removes a newline character after one or more digits followed by a dot.

Comment: This does not seem to work. `$1` would have to be available before `gsub` is being called but it isn't. You could do `gsub(/(\d+\.)\n/) { $1 }` instead.

Comment: oops, sorry .. happend while messing around with other regular expressions :)
Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
str.gsub(/(\d\.)\n/, '\1')
```

replaces all newline characters immediately preceded by a digit (`\d`) and a dot by just that digit and the dot.

Answer (score 1):

```
str.gsub(/(?:\d\.)\n/,'')
```

The stuff in brackets in the regexp (a digit followed by a dot) is matched but not captured, because of the `?:`

Comment: This does not seem to work. Although the `(?:...)` part is not captured it is being replaced.

Answer (score 1):

undur_gongor's answer gives you what you're asking for, but I wonder if it's what you really need.

For example, what if a line legitimately ends in a number, then a dot, like so:

```
str = "1. Hello, World\n 2.\n Good Morning\n 3.Today is 29th January 2012.\n 4. This should be a new line.\n"
```

You would end up with:

`"1. Hello, World\n 2. Good Morning\n 3.Today is 29th January 2012. 4. This should be a new line.\n"`

So you might be better off using:

```
str.gsub(/(^\d+\.|\n\s*\d+\.)\n/, '\1')
```

The `^\d+\.` part of the expression detects the first "line" in the string. The `\n\s*\d+\.` part looks for subsequent "lines"; it accepts infinite whitespace characters before any multi-digit number and a dot.

It's probably not perfect, but covers more scenarios.
Have you any better way of retrieving the data? Parsing strings for data is hard work at the best of times; even more so when the string is badly formatted.